# Verify a shortest path for every vertex in a directed graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path, bellman-ford

Well I'm trying to solve a problem with a more efficient solution and I can't think about anything that would work for sure than the trivial solution, also can't find the same version of this problem in any other sources I came across to so I would love for some help.

Given:

1.A directed graph G, in which every edge has a weight (weight can be negative and G may contain negative cycles).

2.A d[v] field for every vertex.

3.A source vertex s.

How can I verify for every vertex in G if d[v] is the length of the shortest path in G from s to v?

of course I can use Bellman-Ford algorithm and compare each d[v] to the distance that Bellman-Ford gave for v.. but that is pretty naive and not efficient.

Can I do better?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Imagine that you have a completely random array `d`, even in this situation there is a chance that some `d[v]` is equal to the real shortest distance from `s` to `v`. I suppose, that there is no faster way than finding all shortest distances and then comparing them to values from `d`.

Comment: @DAleSo you say that if I want to give an answer to every vertex and not in general ,I must use Bellman-Ford and then do comparisons like I said in the first place?

Comment: Yes, I think so

Answer (score 2):

You can verify if all d[v]'s are correct by using the following property that has to hold for each node v:

The shortest path from s to v has to go via the neighbour n of v for
which d[n] + the cost to get from n to v is the smallest.

So you can just perform the following pseudo code, which runs in O(E) where E is the number of edges.

```
forall v from G:
    if(min(d[n] + w(n, v) | forall n from incoming_neighbours(v)) != d[v]):
         //something is wrong
```

w(n, v) is the weight between node n and v.

However, if you find an error in your d[v]'s using this method you cannot infer which ones are incorrect. In this case, as already mentioned in the comments you will have to preform Bellman-Ford.

Comment: What is n in the algorithm above? And what is the idea behind the for-loop in the boolean check?

Comment: An incoming neighbour node from v (aka a node that has v as neighbour).

Comment: How does this use the source vertex though as described in the problem? Do you just start with s?

Comment: You can start anywhere but you have to check all nodes eventually. You use the shortest dist d[v] from s stored at every node v.

Comment: Ah I see now. That last != d[n], is that suppose to be d[v]? I'm not sure how the minimum of potentially multiple incoming neighbors = d[n] for each neighbor